# PS script to get the folder with no files

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to create a PS script which will loop through the folder and subfolder inside a dir and then get the folder name where there is no files or files which are older than 90 days. Below is the folder structure. Output should be VendorA or VendorB or VendorC. I tried using gci but did not get the desired output.

```
FTP
    VendorA
        folderA
            folder D
        folderB
            Folder E
            Folder F
            Folder G
        folderC
    VendorB
        folderA
            folder D
        folderB
            Folder E
            Folder F
            Folder G
        folderC
    VendorC
        folderA
            folder D
        folderB
            Folder E
            Folder F
            Folder G
        folderC
```

Here is the code that i tried which did get the output however i need to have it csv in  tabular format - Name, Creation time

```
    $gci = gci -Path F:\ftp\NEWFTP -Directory

foreach ($g in $gci)
{
   $child =  Get-ChildItem -Path $g.FullName -Recurse -File
       if ($child -eq $null)
       {
         $g.Name, ($g.CreationTime).ToShortDateString() | Out-File C:\Users\test\Documents\folders.txt -Append
       }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried before?
Post some code, also take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Please show some efforts and if you are stuck anywhere, you can reach out to this website. I would recommend you to look at the [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) cmdlet along with the `-recurse` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not quite clear to me.

- Interpreting the 90 days as MinAge:
- if it's vice versa change `-gt` to `-le`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\20\SO_51443077.ps1

Push-Location 'F:\Ftp\NewFTP'

$Vendors= Get-ChildItem * -Directory
$MinAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

ForEach($Vendor in $Vendors){
   If ((!(Get-ChildItem -Path $Vendor.FullName -File -Recurse).Count) -Or
       (!(Get-ChildItem -Path $Vendor.FullName -File -Recurse |
            Where LastWriteTime -gt $MinAge).Count)) {
      "Folder {0} has no file(s) / (newer than {1}" -f $Vendor,$MinAge
   }
}
Pop.Location
```

Sample output on my last years test folder

```
Folder Q:\Test\2017\01 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\02 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\03 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\04 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\06 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\07 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\08 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
Folder Q:\Test\2017\10 has no file(s) / (newer than 2018-04-21 16:26:05
```

Answer (score 0):

To return empty subfolders of folder x You need to:

```
gci -Path x -Recurse -Directory|%{ if( $null -eq (gci $_.fullname) )  {$_.fullname}}
```

Comment: No need to check against `$null`. You can also just do `| % {if(!(gci $_.fullname)) {$_.fullname}`